# delayed_job Won't Process My Queue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am using the delayed_jobs gem but using it against 2 queues.  I have mapped my models against the correct queues (dbs) to establish correct connections.

The jobs get entered in fine - however, delayed_jobs will process one queue fine but not the other.  I am trying to manually force it to process the email queue but it simply won't.

Is there a way to config/force it to?  Or pass it the correct backend to process?

See below I am counting jobs - getting a correct count.  However, if I try to 'work_off' the queue its showing 0 success/fails.

Pretty sure because its hitting the wrong queue.  Any ideas?

> > Delayed::Worker::Email::Job.count
> >     => 12032
> >
> > Delayed::Worker.new(:backend => Email::Job).work_off
> >     => [0, 0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just going with one queue.  This seemed to work best and save the headache of juggling two.  Would be cool if DJ would eventually support multi-backends/queues.

Comment: Do you have an aversion to [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque)? "Multiple queues" is a standard feature.

Comment: I am trying to run email delayed jobs by   this "Delayed::Worker.new(options).work_off" but its not running any delayed_job, any help would be appriciated